# How to search recipients of previously sent mail?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code which checks the subject in my e-mail and warns me if I already sent an email with this subject. I experienced it would be smarter if it checks for the email address.

I tried substituting "subject" with "recipients" but without success.

```vb
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal thisItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olfolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object

 
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set firstFolder = olNs.Folders("test@dk.com") ' name of my shared inbox
Set olfolder = firstFolder.Folders("sent items")

' iterate thru emails
For Each Item In olfolder.Items
    ' check subject content & date difference
    If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Recipients) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
        ' added this part
        If MsgBox("already sent", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            ' cancel the email
            Cancel = True
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
```

Comment: You can look at the `.to` property or `recipients` is an array, so you'll need to loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `thisItem.Subject` to `thisItem.To`

edit: Nathan_Sav said it all :) `.Recipents` property returns an array so you can loop through it, might as well use `.To` which will return all recipients separated by semicolon

edit2: note there are two other properties `.cc` and `.bcc` if you use them, whilst `.Recipients` array include all of them

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also Nathan. When i change the line to      If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.To) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then  it is not working and it is not working when i change it to .recipients - I've also tried to change the first part, but still doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Where does it fail and what's the error message? Do you get the 'Item.Subject', 'thisItem.To' and 'Item.SentOn' correctly?

Comment: If i change thisItem.Subject to thisItem.To it is not checking correctly and warns me. If I change it to thisItem.Recipients it comes with the following error: Run-Time error '5' : Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: You need to be more specific, what warning message are you getting with thisItem.To? As mentioned above thisItem.Recipients is not going to work as this is an array so you must loop through it

Comment: When I use the thisItem.To the pop-up message doesn't show up even though I'm sending to someone more than one time each month.

Comment: Why don't you debug the code and check the values? You'll have an answer.

Comment: When I try to debug the code it just highlights the line where i have made the change to recipients.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you without seeing the line of code that fails and the error number/description, especially if you made a change. I'm not a psychic ;)

Comment: This is what I've changed it to now: For Each Item In olfolder.Items
    ' check subject content & date difference
 If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Recipients) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
        ' added this part
        If MsgBox("already sent", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            ' cancel the email
            Cancel = True                It comes with this: Run-Time error '5' : Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not ever loop through all items in a folder - this is horribly inefficient. Use `Items.Find` with a restriction on the `Subject` and `SentOn` properties.

For the recipients, you can use a restriction on the `To` property, but keep in mind that on the MAPI level it translates to a restriction on the `PR_DISPLAY_TO` property, which may or may not include the actual email address. OOM does not create subrestrictions on the `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` property. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, its version of `RDOItems.Find/Restrict` allows to specify `Recipients`, `To`, `CC`, `BCC` properties in a query and creates an appropriate restriction on the email address and name of the message recipients.

In the worst case you can restrict on the `Subject` and `SentOn` properties using `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`, and then explicitly loop through the Recipients collection of the returned matches.

Comment: We have a specific folder with only a few massages it needs to loop through, so the only real problem I have is that I need to change it from subject to recipient, but when I use recipient it comes with an error and when i use .to it doesn't show the message even though I'm sending to the same person multiple times.

Comment: So what is your code that processes the recipients? And what is the error?

Comment: This is what I've changed it to now: For Each Item In olfolder.Items
    ' check subject content & date difference
 If InStr(Item.Subject, thisItem.Recipients) And DateDiff("m", Item.SentOn, Now) < 1 Then
        ' added this part
        If MsgBox("already sent", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            ' cancel the email
            Cancel = True                It comes with this: Run-Time error '5' : Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Can you modify your original question with the updated code? It is impossible to read it in a comment.

Comment: Again, you are looping through all items in a folder. Don't do that - use Items.Find/FindNesxt or Items.Restrict. Secondly, Recipients is a collection, not a string. You must loop through that collection to check if the address matches.

Comment: Hello again. I've tried to look up the Items.Find but I'm still not sure how to use it correctly - do you have something you can refer to regarding this. When I want to loop through the recipients I still need to this.subject or?

Comment: First, you use the Items.Find / FindNext loop with a query like "[Subject] = ' some value' ", then for each item returned by Find/FindNext, loop through the recipients.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with that function - do you have somewhere I can read about it and how it is used?

Comment: Which function? See the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.findnext